# APEX: blob data in mysql from query and output as CSV

Tags: oracle-apex, apex, apex-code

Morning folks, could really use your help on this one.
I have a query from a table I need to send out as a CSV attachment on an email using oracle apex. that's the goal of all of this - happy to explore different options/sql to get the same result (through oracle apex)

Example query: `select user, title, dept from user_db where dept = :DEPARTMENT`

My query brings back a huge amount of data (intended)
Based on this, my idea was to make this query into a BLOB and save it to a different table (**TBL_EMAIL_CONTENT**),which I could then use the *APEX_MAIL.ADD_ATTACHMENT* function to bring into an email.

1. I took the query and created a CLOB, then used a separate function to change the CLOB to a BLOB

```
declare
        CSV_CONTENT clob;
        l_BLOB    BLOB;
        crlf        varchar2(2) := chr(13) || chr(10); 
        CSVFILENAME varchar2(255);
    begin

            
    CSV_CONTENT := 'User,'||'Title,'||'Dept,'||crlf;        
            
          for c5 in (select user, title, dept from user_db where dept = :DEPARTMENT)
            LOOP
              CSV_CONTENT := CSV_CONTENT||c5.CONTENT_csv;
              CSVFILENAME := 'Example.csv';
              END LOOP;
            
           L_BLOB := clob_to_blob(CSV_CONTENT);
        
            
        for c6 in (select * from TBL_EMAILCONTENT where EMAIL_ID = 1)
            LOOP
                Update TBL_EMAILCONTENT 
                set 
                filename = CSVFILENAME||'.CSV',
                CONTENT2 = csv_content,
                CONTENT = L_BLOB;
            END LOOP;
    END;
```

The clob_to_blob  function is as follows:

```
    create or replace FUNCTION clob_to_blob(src_clob CLOB) RETURN BLOB IS
        tgt_blob BLOB;
        amount INTEGER := DBMS_LOB.lobmaxsize;
        dest_offset INTEGER := 1;
        src_offset INTEGER  := 1;
        blob_csid INTEGER := nls_charset_id('UTF8');
        lang_context INTEGER := DBMS_LOB.default_lang_ctx;
        warning INTEGER := 0;
    begin
        if src_clob is null then
            return null;
        end if;

        DBMS_LOB.CreateTemporary(tgt_blob, true);
        DBMS_LOB.ConvertToBlob(tgt_blob, src_clob, amount, dest_offset, src_offset, blob_csid, lang_context, warning);
        return tgt_blob;
    end clob_to_blob;
```

I would then send this out using :

```
APEX_MAIL.SEND(
    
      p_to        => 'UKSERVERPATCHING@VODAFONE.COM',
      p_from      => 'ukserverpatching@vodafone.com',
       p_bcc      => 'ukserverpatching@vodafone.com',
      p_body      => to_clob(' '),
      p_body_html => l_body,
      p_subj      => l_subj); 



 for c8 in(
     SELECT  CONTENT,FILENAME,MIMETYPE
     FROM    TBL_EMAILCONTENT
     where   EMAIL_ID = 1)
        
    loop 
           APEX_MAIL.ADD_ATTACHMENT(
            p_mail_id    => l_id,
           p_attachment => c8.CONTENT,
            p_filename   => c8.FILENAME,
           p_mime_type  => c8.MIMETYPE);    
        end loop;
```

Unfortunately, this result makes a CSV that isnt readable with garbled characters in it. Other options ive tried online so far seem to run into problems where the query result is too long to be dealt with via a varchar value.

has anyone came across this before or can point me to an article online that looks to do this sort of thing?

Thanks in advance, really appreciated.